# Adding Comment feature to a JSON data using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I took an AngularJS test yesterday and I was provided two task.

1. I need to display the data of a JSON file on the web page in HTML form.

   - So I took the FreshlyPressed JSON through the link "https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed" and was able to display the thumbnail, post title, content and so on . . on the web page.
2. User must be able to post comments on each post.

This is where I got stuck since I am not sure if it is possible. Is it possible to add a comment feature to an external JSON data such as the one I used? I just want to know the possibilities and the limitation of the external JSON file. Thank you.

This is my js file

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ['ui.bootstrap']);

myapp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get("https://public-api.wordpress.com/rest/v1/freshly-pressed")

    .success(function(response) {
        $scope.names = response.posts;
    });
});

angular.module('myapp')
    .filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function($sce){
        return function(text) {
            return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
        };
    }]);
```

This is my HTML

```
<body data-ng-controller="mainCtrl" data-ng-app="myapp">

<div data-ng-repeat="p in names" class="container">
<img data-ng-src="{{ p.author.avatar_URL }}"><br/>
Author: {{ p.author.nice_name }}<br/>
URL: <a href="{{ p.author.URL }}">{{ p.author.URL }}</a><br/>
Title: {{ p.title }}<br/>
Content:<br/>
<div data-ng-bind-html="p.content | to_trusted"></div><br/>
Comments: {{ p.comments_open }}
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Just add a `comments: []` property to your object being iterated over and push comments.

Comment: I don't think you're expected to hack WordPress.com and alter their JSON feed. A comment system that's local to your app is probably fine ;-)

Comment: Alvaro G. Vicario - Yes that's what I thought, I believe what is being given in the JSON file are the only data you can display on the page. Correct?

Comment: @tymeJV - I am not sure what you mean by add `comment:[]` can you give me a little example please? :)

Comment: Say you have the returned object like `{title: "some title", desc: "some description }` - you can just add a property to that called `comments` - and then do an inner ngRepeat over those.

Comment: @tymeJV - I got it now, wordpress has an API Console that allows you to track comments and so on via site ID and then get the JSON data of that site and display it on the page.

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/

I believe I can take it from here . . thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If You have jsonobj=somevalue //array

var temperature = { temperature: { home: 24, work: 20 }};

jsonObj.data.push(temperature);

Answer (score 0):

I think this sorted out my issue:

https://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/console/

It allows me to extract data from their database on how many comments a post have then get the JSON data and display it on the site. :)

Case solved